# I'm calling FirstPage in HomePage class but its not showing anything?

Tags: flutter, dart

On the homepage when the button is pressed it's doing nothing, I can use navigation but I wanted to know this doesn't work? Why it does not go to the FirstPage class? When I use the Navigation method It does return a container with Text?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:solar/routes.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Explore'),
                onPressed: () {
                  FisrtPage();
                }))
      ],
    ));
  }
}
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FirstPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text('hello'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to use something like `Navigator.push(...)`. Calling `FisrtPage()` does not  navigate to the page it simply calls the `Widget`. [Navigation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to just open new page**

```
open(context, FirstPage())

open(BuildContext context,StatefulWidget whichIsOpen){

  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => whichIsOpen));
}
```

**If you want to open new page and want to finish last:**

```
 openReplace(context, FirstPage())

openReplace(BuildContext context,StatefulWidget whichIsOpen){

  Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => whichIsOpen));

}
```

**If you want to get value from the second page to one page (like on activity result)**

```
var value  = await  openWait(context, FirstPage())

Future openWait(BuildContext context,StatefulWidget whichIsOpen) async{

  final result = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => whichIsOpen),
  );

  return result;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try changing this `onPressed` method using Navigator:**

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage()),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Navigator** to navigate between the screens. Write the following code inside **onPressed** of HomePage Raised Button.

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage()),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add the `Navigator` to your next page:

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage()),
  );
}
```

And don't forget to add `Scaffold` in your code:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      child: Container(
        // YOUR CODE HERE
      ),
    );
}
```